# xsl how to split a node into multiple

Tags: xml, xslt, split

I'm new to XSL and I need some details please to implement this process.
I would like to implement a template with xsl to obtain mutiple outputbasing on the parent Node, could you help me please.

```
This is the input required now :

<parent>
<company>
<liv dt="2015-10-22" >
<Qty type ="NET"> 55</Qty> 
<Qty type ="FAR"> 558</Qty>
<Qty type ="MAE"> 1222</Qty>
<HR amt ="NET"> 55</HR> 
<Risk> adsm </Risk>
</liv>

<company>
</parent>

this is the output desired:I need to seprate the companies by Type, the other records should always appear as they were, Thanks a lot for the help:

<parent>

<company>
<liv dt="2015-10-22" ><Qty type ="NET"> 55</Qty> 
<HR amt ="NET"> 55</HR> 
<Risk> adsm </Risk>  
</liv>
</company>

<company>
<liv dt="2015-11-1" ><Qty type ="FAR"> 558</Qty> 
<HR amt ="NET"> 55</HR> 
<Risk> adsm </Risk>
</liv>
</company>

<company>
<liv dt="2015-10-28" ><Qty type ="MAE"> 1222</Qty>
<HR amt ="NET"> 55</HR> 
<Risk> adsm </Risk>
</liv>
</company>

</parent>
```

Comment: Your question is not clear. Why are FAR and MAE together, but NET is apart? And what is the meaning of `new value:`?  Please show the **exact** output you expect. Also indicate if using XSLT 1.0 or 2.0.

Comment: Sorry no new value is a comment in fact

Answer (score 0):

Write a template for `company` elements that processes the children and then in the template for `liv` wrap it with the parent:

```
<xsl:transform xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">

    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="company">
        <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="liv">
        <xsl:element name="{name(..)}">
            <xsl:copy-of select="."/>
        </xsl:element>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:transform>
```

Online at http://xsltransform.net/3NJ38YT.

For the edited input and output sample more code is needed, here is the XSLT:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<xsl:transform xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">

    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>
    <xsl:output indent="yes"/>

    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="@*|node()" name="identity" mode="sub">
        <xsl:param name="anchor"/>
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()" mode="sub">
                <xsl:with-param name="anchor" select="$anchor"/>
            </xsl:apply-templates>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="company">
        <xsl:apply-templates select="liv/Qty" mode="split"/>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="Qty" mode="split">
        <xsl:apply-templates select="ancestor::company" mode="sub">
            <xsl:with-param name="anchor" select="current()"/>
        </xsl:apply-templates>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="Qty" mode="sub">
        <xsl:param name="anchor"/>
        <xsl:if test="generate-id() = generate-id($anchor)">
            <xsl:call-template name="identity"/>
        </xsl:if>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:transform>
```

Online at http://xsltransform.net/3NJ38YT/1.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help, I want to know somthing  please ,for the node parent you didn't mention it in the path it is not necessary ?

Comment: The first template in the stylesheet takes care of any nodes which need to be copied (like the `parent` element), then we add more specific templates for those nodes that need to be transformed.

Comment: Please edit your question with any additional code samples, well-formatted please, so that we can infer what you want to achieve.

Comment: yes sure, I have modifed the code below as it is required.thanks a lot  for your  help

Comment: Thanks for the Help, this solution resolved finally the problem.Could you please indicate for me some links that conatin intersting docs for XSLT :)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/tags/xslt/info already has lots of links, start there. Generally you need to understand that XSLT uses XPath, so learning XPath to navigate in XML documents to select nodes, is a good foundation before using XSLT.

Comment: @user3145787, if the problem is solved then please accept the answer so your question is marked as solved.

Comment: yes The problem is resolved, how can I please accept the answer?

Comment: See http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/23138/how-to-accept-the-answer-on-stack-overflow.

Comment: Hi All, how could I please change the XSLT file to eliminate the record with 55 Qty before Processing? Thanks.